# Heroku node.js keeps crashing because of node_modules?

Tags: node.js, heroku

This is the heroku logs

```
2017-12-13T16:08:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-12-13T16:08:46.328161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-12-13T16:08:46.498068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490378+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:538
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490391+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490391+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490392+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490392+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './decimal128'
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490393+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:6:22)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490396+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490396+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490397+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490397+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.490398+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
2017-12-13T16:08:53.582814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-13T16:08:53.555998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-13T16:08:51.503070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-12-13T16:10:20.313936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-13T16:10:23.590155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-12-13T16:10:26.548414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463026+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:538
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463042+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463042+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463043+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463044+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './decimal128'
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463045+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463045+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463047+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:6:22)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463049+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463050+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.463050+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
2017-12-13T16:10:26.576992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Via trial and error and using the heroku rollback it seems that the problem isn't in my app.js file but in the node_modules. However I can't seem to find a fix. I've tried reinstalling the node_modules.

It works locally but not when I deploy it on Heroku.

also suddenly I have a package-lock.json file. perhaps thats is a clue?

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about the decimal128 module, I would double check the relative path to the module from the file that is requiring it. Looks like right now it's looking for it in the same folder as the file "/decimal128".

Comment: I don't have a module.js anywhere in my directory. should I add it?

Comment: also the decimal128 module is there next to the files that requests it. What I'm wondering though is the /app/ start of that path correct? there isn't an app folder or is that my main project folder?

Comment: That sounds correct, are you committing the local /node_modules folder when you push to heroku? That might be causing an issue since heroku runs npm install automatically.

Comment: I'm not committing the local node_modules folder. Should I be?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by going through everything updating everything and downgrading mongodb to "mongodb": "2.2.33"